# Discrete subgroups of isometry group of proper metric space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gr.group-theory

Let $X$ be a proper metric space and consider its isometry group $\mathrm{ISO}(X)$ endowed with the compact-open topology. Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\mathrm{ISO}(X)$.

Consider the following conditions on $G$:

(1) $G$ acts properly on $X$, i.e. any two points $x$ and $y$ in $X$ have neighborhoods $U_x$ and $U_y$ such that there are only a finite number of group elements $g \in G$ with $g(U_x)$ meeting $U_y$.

(2) $G$ is a discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{ISO}(X)$.

(3) The orbit $Gx$ is a discrete subset of $X$ for all $x \in X$.

My question: Is (1) equivalent with (2) or is (2) equivalent with (3), or neither? Does anything change if one assumes also that $X$ is CAT(0) and/or $G$ acts cocompactly.

Comment: Could you give some context for the question?  Did it arise in your research, or are you just curious? As Misha says below, it looks a lot like a homework question.  I'm going to vote to close, although the question could be suitable for MO with more context.

Comment: It was not a homework question, just a question I asked myself. 
But I see now that the answer is not very difficult. I was just forgetting about Arzela-Ascoli theorem. So thanks for the hint Misha.



Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice homework problem for a graduate class in metric geometry or geometric group theory right after the students learned the  definition of uniform convergence on compacts and the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. (No, the students do not need to know what CAT(0) spaces are.)

Comment: @Misha: this should be a comment (since you are not actually answering the question).

Comment: Igor, I feel that this is a hwk question, so it would be best to give a hint rather than an answer. Being new to MO, I am not quite sure what is the policy on this...

Comment: Misha - the usual policy is to write a polite comment to that effect, possibly refer the asker to math.stackexchange (with the caveat that if it's a homework question then that should be clearly stated) and vote to close (if you have 3000+ reputation, as you no doubt will before long).